# Class creation unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, macos, class, unrecognized-selector

I'm learning Objective-C. 
I'm at the point of creating a simple class but when compiling, after the expected result, I get this errors.

```
2014-05-08 10:15:47.998 ClassCreation[978:903] This is a method call in the new object!
2014-05-08 10:15:48.007 ClassCreation[978:903] -[Employee setName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10010c850
...
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
(gdb)
```

Here it is the Employee.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface Employee : NSObject

// properties
@property NSString *name;
@property NSDate *hireDate;
@property int employeeNumber;

-(void) someMethod;

@end
```

Here it is the Employee.m

```
#import "Employee.h"

@implementation Employee

// matching the method definition that is defined in the interface
-(void) someMethod {
NSLog(@"This is a method call in the new object!");
}

@end
```

Here it is the main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Employee.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    //  inside here, I instantiate a new object of my new employee class
    Employee *fred = [[Employee alloc] init];

    // call a method of our new object
    [fred someMethod];

    // change a property of new object
    [fred setName:@"Fred Smith"];

}
return 0;
}
```

I'm on 10.6.8 with Xcode 4.2

Comment: I think you should synthesise your properties, if you are not on Xcode 4.4 or later. Could anyone please confirm this? Thanks.

Comment: yes, its true. i think the old Xcode is better if you want to learn Objective-C. All this authosynthetisizing stuff makes it really easy for newbies to mix the concepts of iVars and properties. With Xcode 4.2 there is no autosynthesis, so you get an error, and you have a chance to learn what a property actually is. This is a really important step if you want to become a pro.

Comment: do you have a warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With XCode 4.2 you need to add the line

```
@synthesize name,hireDate,employeeNumber;
```

to your Employee.m file after the @implementation line

Auto synthesis of properties only became available with XCode 4.4 - http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html

You should look at upgrading your XCode version

Comment: if this is the case, then he should have gotten a warning

Comment: No, because main.m includes Employee.h, which contains the @property definitions, so the compiler knows that the property exists. When compiling main.m it doesn't look at Employee.m so it doesn't know that the setter & getter methods are missing. Because objective c binds the selector at runtime you don't get a linker error either.

Comment: I am talking about when compiling Employee.m.

Comment: As Employee is just a storage object and there are no methods in the .m and no reference to the properties there may not have even been a warning there - I don't have XCode 4.2 to check. Even if there was a warning, people often ignore warnings (they shouldn't, but they do). The warning won't stop the build and you get the runtime crash that the OP experienced

Comment: When the pre-auto-syntehsize compiler compiles an `@implementation`, and it does not contain an implementing method, `@synthesize`, or `@dynamic` for a declared property, it will be a warning.

Comment: Ok, but warnings don't prevent the code from compiling...you just get a runtime error